# How to nested query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How to index nested objects in Pymongo so that I can perform full text search. For example I've the collection object like this...

```
{
   "_id":"ObjectId("   "5e8b0fa1c869790699efdb2d"   ")",
   "xmlfileid": "334355343343223567",
   "threads":{
      "threads_participants":{
         "participant":[
            {
               "@reference": rits_dbx_1
            },
            {
               "@reference": rits_dbx_2
            }
         ]
      },
      "thread":{
         "namedAnchor":"{' ': 'NORP', 'Ho': 'PERSON', 'Lets': 'PERSON', 'Boris Johnson': 'PERSON', 'Britain': 'GPE'}",
         "selectedText":{
            "fragment":[
               {
                  "@class":"next_steps",
                  "#text":"rits_dbx_1 said hello this is a good site."
               },
               {
                  "@class":"other",
                  "#text":"rits_dbx_1 said ho ho."
               },
               {
                  "@class":"other",
                  "#text":"rits_dbx_1 said lets put some meaningful stuff here."
               },
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I've placed search box in my website and when user types the `#text` in search box I want to display the `#text` and `class` and the `xmlfileid`

So far I've created index using below command. And I don't know it's the right way to get the result and also please help with query too.

```
db.xml_collection.createIndex({"threads.thread.selectedText.fragment": "text"})
```

In my python code I've this but that prints nothing

```
result = collection.find({"$text": {"$search": "ho ho"}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is wrong.

> MongoDB provides `text` indexes to support text search queries on string content. **text** indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

If you want to index only `#text` field, change your index to this:

```
db.xml_collection.createIndex({"threads.thread.selectedText.fragment.#text": "text"})
```

Also, you may create [Wildcard text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes) and MongoDB will index all `key:value` pairs (where `value` is string / array of string)

```
db.xml_collection.createIndex({"$**": "text"})
```

**Note:** You need to drop any previous `text` indexes for this collection

Comment: Thanks it worked. I will go with wildcard since our requirement slightly changes.